# Core Data NSPredicate for (select ... where not in (select))

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

Is there a way to simulate the Sub Select Methods without pulling out the whole set that you want to limit against.

In this question 
[Core Data: Query objectIDs in a predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941357/core-data-query-objectids-in-a-predicate)

they gave a demonstration of using the not in limit. But it shows using a list of objects that you would want to limit against.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self IN %@)", arrayOfExcludedObjects];
```

Is this the only way to do this or is there a way to limit against a sub query so I dont have to get the results of a query I want to limit against.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out there does not appear to be a way to do a join in CoreData.

I could potentially open the SQLite database up manually and join the data to get the results I was looking for, But I would lose the power of core data if I went that route.

It seems the best way to accomplish this is to run the query I want and get back the objects that I want limited out, and put those into the arrayOfExcludedObjects. Alternatively I can add the objects I want to keep to an array and add a predicate with "(self IN %@)" and it would accomplish the same thing.

The extra functionality I gain with core data occasionally gives a loss of other functionality.

Perhaps someday apple will add those types of predicates.