# NSPredicate to return all except given object

Tags: core-data, swiftui, nspredicate

can't find syntax of NSPredicate which allows me to fetch all the objects, except one given

```
  fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF != %@", setting.objectID)
```

My entity does not have any stored ID. somewhere in comments found that syntaxes but it does not work:

```
Generic parameter 'Subject' could not be inferred
```

any ideas how to filter all objects but one given, without filtering several properties?

that's my view (using SwiftUI):

```
struct SettingsChoiseView: View {
    @Binding var actualSetting: Settings
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var moc: NSManagedObjectContext
    @FetchRequest var avalibleSettings: FetchedResults<Settings>

     init(setting: Binding<Settings>) {
         let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest< Settings> = Settings.fetchRequest()
         fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ Settings.name, ascending: true),
                                    NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \ Settings.height, ascending: true)]
         fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "!(name = %@ && height == %d)", setting.name.wrappedValue, setting.height.wrappedValue)

            self._avalibleSettings = FetchRequest(fetchRequest:fetchRequest)
    }
    var body: some View{
        ...
    }
}
```

`Settings` is `NSManagedObject` with properties name and height.

Comment: How do you initialise `fetchRequest`?

Comment: @pbasdf updated post

Comment: The topic [Core Data: Query objectIDs in a predicate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941357/core-data-query-objectids-in-a-predicate) should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanx to @Asperi, I get that:

```
        fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "NOT (self in %@)", [setting.wrappedValue])
```