# SwiftUI Selection Sets and Core Data - setting up NSPredicate with the object identifier

Tags: swift, core-data, nspredicate, swiftui-list, multipleselection

If you combine CoreData with SwiftUI Lists you can configure multiple selection of list items if the selection parameter of the list is `Set<Item.ID>`?

The question is: if you have a set of `Item.ID`s that are given to you by the SwiftUI List selection, what is the correct way to fetch only those items in another view with Core Data?

The thinking...

To setup selection you need somewhere to hold the the references to the selected items.

`@State var selectedItems : Set<Item.ID>?`

```
List(fetchedItems, selection: $selectedItems) { item in

...
}
```

In a master detail interface, you could pass the selection set to the Detail view. Your detail view has to be able to handle the set of object identifiers passed to it.

If you are using `NavigationSplitView` you will have some reference to a detail view

`DetailView(selection : selectedItems)`

So you are passing a *set* of `Item.ID`s to the `DetailView`, not just one value.

If you have setup DetailView in the standard Core Data manner you typically have

`var detailItems: FetchedResults<Item>` but you now want to find all the Items that match anything in the set of Item.ID the possible solution appears to be to redefine the `nsPredicate`. (You might do this in an initialiser ... still figuring out the architecture).

```
// in the DetailView, if the selection set has changed, update the predicate
.onChange(of: selected) { newValue in
   detailItems.nsPredicate = newValue.isEmpty ? nil : NSPredicate(format: "objectID IN %@", Array(newValue) )
```

However, there is a mismatch between `objectID` in the predicate format string and the set of `Item.ID`s. This actually crashes the app with an SQL error. Sorry app is not in a state to pull the errors - I'm backing out of the first experiment and ran into different Xcode weirdness.

In a non-Core Data project you would filter out only those items that matched an `Identifiable` where `let id = UUID()` using something like `collection.filter { set.contains($0.id) }`

Comment: Try using `self` in the predicate instead of `objectID` and if that doesn’t help then add the error message to the question.

Comment: Adding `self` didn't work. I've rebuilt a basic example from the default Core Data template. The error is: `unimplemented SQL generation for predicate : (objectID CONTAINS {ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000015ca670)})`

Comment: “Adding”? Did you do that or did you mean to write replacing?

Comment: objectID IN {ObjectIdentifier(0x00006000015ca670), not CONTAINS

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean but this is what I meant: `NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", Array(newValue) )`

Comment: `NSPredicate(format: "self IN %@", Array(newValue))` doesn't crash but the results continue to be empty. `newValue` will be a `Set<Item.ID>` so this seems to be trying to compare `Item.ID`s with `Item`s - correct? Or is there some implicit reference to the ID via self?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/941357/core-data-query-objectids-in-a-predicate seems to suggest that the objectID is used in the query.

Comment: looking at `self`, `id` and `objectID` for a core data object they are comprised of different content. `self` <Item: 0x60000363d540> (entity: Item; id: 0xbc381d0ed9e6c94d <x-coredata://BA6CC4D6-A006-492D-A299-4F0FE2F82541/Item/p1>; data: {
    timestamp = "2023-09-16 08:04:49 +0000";
}), `id` ObjectIdentifier(0x000060000363d540) and `objectID` 0xbc381d0ed9e6c94d <x-coredata://BA6CC4D6-A006-492D-A299-4F0FE2F82541/Item/p1>. The selection Set<Item.ID> contains ObjectIdentifier(0x000060000363d540). self compared to ObjectIdentifier will produce no match in the predicate.